# What is the correct way to migrate a program from an old Android Studio version to a newer one?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm curious about this. I made an Android program using an earlier version of the Google Android Studio (I believe 2.3.x), and recently upgraded to a newer version that came out (3.1.2), however, when I tried to bring in the program directly to this version and fire it up, I got a lot of compile errors due to various things being out of date. I tried to fix these in a rather ad-hoc manner because I could not find any comprehensive information despite much googling detailing how to properly migrate a project and it seemed to work (and so I can't post what they were), but now it seems to have broken again (perhaps because of another automatic upgrade) and I am getting this, for which searching has not yielded anything helpful:

> Could not find recyclerview-v7.jar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/27.1.1/recyclerview-v7-27.1.1.jar
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
>   Open Android SDK Manager

Yet I go to the "Android SDK Manager" (that shows as a link in the output) and it says the relevant package is both installed and apparently at its latest version (since it does not say any updates are available). Moreover I was not aware I was even using the control "recyclerview" in the program, so I am rather puzzled as to why I am getting this error and I suspect it is because I did the migration wrong (not surprising due to the frustrating lack of information). I still have the project original from the earlier version so I could repeat it, but I'd like to then know how to do it *correctly* as I suspect this is resulting from the fact that I don't really know what I'm doing - and so what is the way to do that?

FWIW, the present project build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sg.simetricclock.kumari.metricclock"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha1'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
}
```

Comment: Add `jcenter()` under `maven {` block, and combine all your `dependencies` blocks into one (also remove duplicate `constraint-layout` lines)

Answer (score 0):

First Change Your `Compile` statement to `Implimentation` and Then Change Your `Targeted SDK Version 28` And Then SYNC Your Project. I Hope After That You Will Not get Error